# Assigning List Values through Try and Except

Tags: python, list, try-catch, except

I am currently analyzing this health dataset and part of my analysis is looking at individuals that have died within a year of being admitted into the Emergency Room. I have come up with the differences between admittance date and death date but I would like to have those that are still alive say "still alive" in their respective cell. Is there a way to include that in the "except" clause?

My current code provided below. I currently get the differences but for those where the value was a Nonetype, I am returned zeros.

```
differences = []
for i in range(889):
    try:
        differences.append(relativedelta(death_date_new[i], admittance_date[i]).years)
    except TypeError:
        i = "Still Alive"
        differences.append(i)
```

Comment: You shouldn't redefine 'i' where you have `i = "Still Alive"`. It has potential to mess with your loop. Change 'i' to 'status' and see how it works. Or even further: `differences.append('Still Alive')`

Comment: I guess the TypeError can occur when there is not death_date_new, so death_date_new can be None or datetime value ?